# I made a 6-DOF arm using xacro , its moving in gazebo but when i use tf_echo , the orientation and position of a frame does not change overtime

Tags: ros-melodic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

when arm moves in gazebo the orientation and position of a frame in a link should change over time.

but when i use rosrun tf tf_echo [frame1]  [frame2] the position and orientation remain unchanged.

please help me out with this.

my model moves in gazebo but not in rviz..

thanks in advance

Here is my  launch file

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<launch>
<group ns="/arm">
<param name="robot_description" command="$(find xacro)/xacro $(find robo_arm)/urdf/robo_dis.xacro"/>
    <arg name="x" default="0"/>
    <arg name="y" default="0"/>
    <arg name="z" default="0.5"/>
    
      <node name="mybot" pkg="gazebo_ros" type="spawn_model" output="screen"
          args="-urdf -param robot_description -model arm -x $(arg x) -y $(arg y) -z $(arg z)" />
     <rosparam command="load" file="$(find robo_arm)/config/joints.yaml" />
     <node name="controller_spawner" pkg="controller_manager" type="spawner"
            respawn="false" output="screen" ns="/arm"
            args="--namespace=/arm
            joint_state_controller
            joint1_position_controller
            joint2_position_controller
            joint3_position_controller
            joint4_position_controller
            --timeout 60">
     </node>
   <node name="joint_state_publisher" pkg="joint_state_publisher" type="joint_state_publisher">
  </node>
  <!-- Combine joint values -->
  <node name="robot_state_publisher" pkg="robot_state_publisher" type="robot_state_publisher"/>
  
</group>
```

**Topic List**

```
/arm/joint1_position_controller/command
/arm/joint1_position_controller/pid/parameter_descriptions
/arm/joint1_position_controller/pid/parameter_updates
/arm/joint1_position_controller/state
/arm/joint2_position_controller/command
/arm/joint2_position_controller/pid/parameter_descriptions
/arm/joint2_position_controller/pid/parameter_updates
/arm/joint2_position_controller/state
/arm/joint3_position_controller/command
/arm/joint3_position_controller/pid/parameter_descriptions
/arm/joint3_position_controller/pid/parameter_updates
/arm/joint3_position_controller/state
/arm/joint4_position_controller/command
/arm/joint4_position_controller/pid/parameter_descriptions
/arm/joint4_position_controller/pid/parameter_updates
/arm/joint4_position_controller/state
/arm/joint_states 
/clock
/gazebo/link_states
/gazebo/model_states
/gazebo/parameter_descriptions
/gazebo/parameter_updates
/gazebo/set_link_state
/gazebo/set_model_state
/rosout
/rosout_agg 
/tf
/tf_static
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/351369/i-made-a-6-dof-arm-using-xacro-,-its-moving-in-gazebo-but-when-i-use-tf_echo-,-the-orientation-and-position-of-a-frame-does-not-change-overtime./) by [saztyga](https://answers.ros.org/users/54402/saztyga/) on ROS Answers with karma: 5 on 2020-05-04

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jarvisschultz](https://answers.ros.org/users/1272/jarvisschultz/) on 2020-05-04**:
Does your model have a [joint_state_controller](http://wiki.ros.org/joint_state_controller) to publish joint states to ROS? Have you loaded the corresponding URDF to the parameter server and setup the `robot_state_publisher` to publish the `tf` data associated with the joint states? These are all steps that are usually followed to have a moving Gazebo model be reflected in the ROS `tf` tree. Without more information about your particular setup, it will be very challenging to provide much help on this question.

**Comment by [jarvisschultz](https://answers.ros.org/users/1272/jarvisschultz/) on 2020-05-04**:
The [Gazebo ros_control](http://gazebosim.org/tutorials/?tut=ros_control) tutorial has a good explanation and example of how these pieces are supposed to fit together.

**Comment by [saztyga](https://answers.ros.org/users/54402/saztyga/) on 2020-05-04**:
sir, Please check my topic list and launch file...each link broadcasting tf data but when i move the joints by publising messages, tf data remains unchanges..its should  changed.

**Comment by [saztyga](https://answers.ros.org/users/54402/saztyga/) on 2020-05-04**:
Thanks a lot Sir,
by removing node joint_state_publisher i am able to get desired results.
thanks a lot

**Comment by [jarvisschultz](https://answers.ros.org/users/1272/jarvisschultz/) on 2020-05-04**:
Excellent! I converted my comment to an answer since that turned out to be a correct guess.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Just glancing at your launch files, my guess is that both the `joint_state_publisher` and `gazebo` are publishing on the `/arm/joint_states` topic. I'd look at `rostopic info /arm/joint_states` and `rosnode info /arm/robot_state_publisher`. Ideally, only `gazebo` would publish joint state information, and the `robot_state_publisher` would be subscribed to that topic.

---

Originally posted by [jarvisschultz](https://answers.ros.org/users/1272/jarvisschultz/) with karma: 9031 on 2020-05-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1